# How to know if webview has fully loaded or cancelled due to redirect?

Tags: android, android-webview

If I load **A.com** into a `new WebView(no history)` and the url is redirected to **B.com,** WebView will remain black if **WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading** returns true.

I want to close the WebView in this case, but how to determine if it is blank due to redirection.

Not working with `onPageFinished()`, It is always called even if it is redirected

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains(B.com)){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**See you can follow this code,**

1. init WebView

   ```
   webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
   webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
   webView.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
   webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
   ```
2. set webview listeners

   ```
   webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
       override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
           super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
           url?.let {
              // do what you want here, for example
               if(it != "determine url"){ 
               val returnIntent = Intent()
               returnIntent.putExtra("tag_bool", true)
               setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
               finish()
               }
           }
       }
       override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest,
                                    error: WebResourceError) {
           super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
           // show error 
           return true
       }

         override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: 
    WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
           // you can handle loading ui and show progress
           view?.loadUrl(url)
           return true
       }
   ```

   **do not forget add this line in application tag in Manifest file**

   ```
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   ```

you  can know more about it, check this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic